# Is it possible to add the same note with different accidentals in Guitar Pro 6?

Tags: guitar-pro

I want to add (in a single stem) the same note with different accidentals. Like, in the following example, in the third stem I want to have both G sharp and G natural.

[image]

Is there any way to do this in Guitar Pro 6?

I know that I can use Ab as G# or Fx as G natural, but I'm wondering if I can insert G with different accidentals somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is. I can think of two ways.

The easiest way would be to write the note as the enharmonic equivalent (Ab) and then click on the change accidental button (icon is a sharp and flat symbol, 5th row, 6th icon) in the side menu or press ctrl-alt-8 on the note to change it to a G#.

Secondly, you can use voices (The small 1,2,3,4 at the bottom of the score editor, above the timeline) to add the second note on a second voice.

If you need clearer instructions, I can upload a screenshot but I hope you can follow this.